# Access query to group by and select two random rows per group

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

The goal is to try and obtain two random sample cases per handler ID.

The data for this project is below.

```
ID  Complaint Handler   Handler ID  Reference   Outcome Handler Notes
1   John Doe    h384    R38423  Uphold  Not Applicable
2   Ryan Jones  h632    R38482  Uphold  Not Applicable
3   Chris Smith h238    R84823  Defend  Not Applicable
4   Emily Surry h634    R48384  Reject  Not Applicable
5   Elle Smith  h123    R48823  Uphold  Not Applicable
6   Jane Doe    h324    R48282  Uphold  Not Applicable
7   Joe Bloggs  h538    R83322  Reject  Not Applicable
8   Ryan Jones  h632    R38299  Defend  Not Applicable
9   Chris Smith h238    R83482  Reject  Not Applicable
10  Chris Smith h238    R91823  Reject  Not Applicable
11  Joe Bloggs  h538    R18291  Uphold  Not Applicable
```

I have used the following query to select all the unique case handler references.

```
SELECT Cases.[Handler ID]
FROM Cases
GROUP BY Cases.[Handler ID];
```

I then need to loop through all these unique references and execute the following query

```
SELECT TOP 2 * 
FROM Cases
WHERE Cases.[Handler ID] = 'XXXXXX'
ORDER BY Rnd(ID)
```

An example of the result would be

```
ID  Complaint Handler   Handler ID  Reference   Outcome Handler Notes
1   John Doe    h384    R38423  Uphold  Not Applicable
2   Ryan Jones  h632    R38482  Uphold  Not Applicable
3   Chris Smith h238    R84823  Defend  Not Applicable
4   Emily Surry h634    R48384  Reject  Not Applicable
5   Elle Smith  h123    R48823  Uphold  Not Applicable
6   Jane Doe    h324    R48282  Uphold  Not Applicable
7   Joe Bloggs  h538    R83322  Reject  Not Applicable
8   Ryan Jones  h632    R38299  Defend  Not Applicable
10  Chris Smith h238    R91823  Reject  Not Applicable
11  Joe Bloggs  h538    R18291  Uphold  Not Applicable
```

Result example: Row 9 randomly removed as there was three Chris Smith's.

No other rows affected as there is 2 or less results.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work in MS Access:

```
select c.*
from cases as c
where c.id in (select top 2 c2.id
               from cases as c2
               where c2.handler = c.handler
               order by rnd(-Timer() * c2.id)
              );
```

Comment: This does not apple the group by query for handler id?

Comment: It's not necessary.